# Any way of sorting CoreData entity after fetch request?

Tags: swift, core-data

The only way I found of sorting FetchedRequest is with NSSortDescriptor that is done when fetching. But, I want to implement different types of sorting (e.g. by name, by amount increasing, by amount decreasing), what is the way to do it? compare each fetched item attribute that I need to sort by and decide, shall one of them go upper or lower in list?

Comment: You need to research how to sort an array of objects, there should be plenty of information available

Comment: "I want to implement different types of sorting (e.g. by name, by amount increasing, by amount decreasing)" seems to be able to put into a NSSortDescriptor to me, basic sorting. It's more efficient in the sort in done in the query. Else, it's about sorting an array, which is really basic, and depends on your needs. Your question is too broad for now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions. I'll take some time on research about sorting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need NSSortDescriptor. You can sort your fetched array afterwards aswell.

See this example, I use to sort my dates by startDate

```
ForEach(self.events.sorted {
    $0.startDate < $1.startDate
}, id:\.id) { event in
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this, it's actually pretty easy

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.serialNum, ascending: true)
    ]) 
var items: FetchedResults<Item> // fetching core data
@State var SortedItems:[Item] = [] // creating an additional array
```

Sorting by increasing amount looks like so:

```
SortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.amount < $1.amount}) // giving our additional array a value of FetchRequest, but sorted by increasing amount
```

and sorting by decreasing amount looks like so:

```
SortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.amount > $1.amount}) // giving our additional array a value of FetchRequest, but sorted by decreasing amount
```